# How can SOLR be made to boost within result set?

Tags: solr

I have indexed some documents that have title, content and keyword (multi-value).

I want to *search* on title and content, and then, within these results *boost* by keyword.

I have set up my qf as such:

```
  <str name="qf">
    content^0.5 title^1.0
  </str>
```

And my bq as such:

```
<str name="bq">keyword:(*.*)^1.0</str>
```

But I'm fairly sure that this is boosting on all keywords (not just ones matching my search term)

Does anyone know how to achieve what I want (I'm using the DisMax query request handler btw.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's how the boost works. Boost is supposed to specify the importance of a match on a specific field.

So by doing something like `content^0.5 title^1.0 keyword^5.0`, you can make your queries give extra importance to the keyword.

You might be able to force it by doing a complex query. For instance you can use the "+" operator to make it required. So something like this if you were searching for "query":

```
+(content:query title:query) keyword:query
```